# Why use -D instead of -P to activate a maven profile?

Tags: java, maven

e.g.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>rofileX</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The profile could have been activated using -ProfileX, why am I seeing people bother to add in an activation property, e.g.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>rofileX</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>oX</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

to allow activation using -DoX?

Is there any reason to use -D insteal of -P? Or you can achieve more things with -D as oppose to -P?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One usage of `-Dmyproperty` instead of `-Pmyprofile` is to activate several profiles using only one parameter.

Moreover, you can reuse the `-Dmyproperty` in other parts of your POM, using `${myproperty}`.

Answer (score 1):

The property does not necessarily has to be set via the `-D` maven option, it may also be a system property. So it is possible to switch between profiles without changing the invocation.

[edit]
from the[Maven documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html):

```
-D, --define <arg>
Defines a system property

...

Properties defined on the command line are also available as properties to be used in a Maven POM or Maven Plugin
```

Comment: Yea, but my question is more about an explicit property name for that purpose rather than a system property. I think Guil has a closer answer. Thanks.